Multiplication of $\mathrm{U}(3)$ matrices
On this page of this paper:



I am unable to understand how they multiplied the $3\times 3$ $\mathrm{U}(3)$ matrix with $T_{3,2}$, which is a $2\times 2$ matrix, in Eqs. (26) to (28). Can anyone please explain?

Don't use images/screenshots for text and equations. Instead, type the relevant passage and use MathJax for math symbols.

$T_{3,2}$ is really a $3\times 3$ matrix as well. $\mathcal{U}(2)$ is an arbitrary $2\times 2$ unitary matrix:
$$\mathcal{U}(2)=\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}.$$
The notation
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&\mathcal{U}(2)\end{pmatrix}$$
is really just shorthand for
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&A&B\\ 0&C&D\end{pmatrix}.$$
As such, both $\mathcal{U}(3)$ and $T_{3,2}$ are really $3\times 3$ matrices, and can be multiplied as you'd expect.

Thanks but can you also tell how they got the matrix after multiplication of U(2) and T3,2; I am not getting zero values in positions they are showing here in screenshot.

@shome These look like Givens rotations, but it is not clear to me how they zero element (1,3) using the (3,2) matrix
